# Export data in ag-grid for cell renderer

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ag-grid

I'm using ag-grid and I have a column definition as following :

```
{
    headerName: "Color",
    valueGetter: function (params) {
        return JSON.parse(params.data.color).name;
    },
    field: 'color',
    cellRenderer: function (params) {
        if (angular.isDefined(params.data) && angular.isDefined(params.data.color)) {
            var color = JSON.parse(params.data.color);
            return '<div style="width: 50px; height: 18px; background-color:' + color.htmlValue + ';"></div>';
        }
    },
    suppressMenu: true,
    suppressSorting: true
}
```

When I export the grid in CSV format, I get undefined for the color column, which is a cell renderer, I searched for a solution for this and I found this in the official documentation :

> The raw values, and not the result of cell renderer, will get used,
>   meaning:
>
> - Cell Renderers will NOT be used.
> - Value Getters will be used.
> - Cell Formatters will NOT be used (use processCellCallback instead).

As you can see I'm already using a valueGetter but I always get undefined in the exported data for the color column.

How can I solve this ?

Comment: Could you debug and show us what's there in `params.data.color`?

Comment: @Paritosh When the grid is loaded `params.data.color` has a value but when I call the export function, I get undefined in the cellRenderer

Comment: Anyway to get it without using the Enterprise (paid version of ag-grid)???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could solve it by using **processCellCallback** when exporting to CSV. This way you can see and control exactly what is going to be exported.

Besides the column definition, you can pass other parameters to your grid options.

From ag-grid docs: [What gets exported](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-export/#what-gets-exported)

> - The raw values, and not the result of cell renderer, will get used,
>     meaning:
>
>   - ...
>   - Cell Formatters will NOT be used (**use processCellCallback instead**).

So, let's say that you have your column definition in a variable called `columnDefs`. Now you pass that to your `gridOptions`.

```
const gridOptions = {
  columnDefs: columnDefs,
}
```

The latter code should work. So, now you want to handle the clicking on `CSV Export` on the context menu (You can also do it with a custom button if you may).

Export to CSV:

Now you have to add the provided `getContextMenuItems` function to you `gridOptions` object. For more info: [Configuring the Context Menu](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-context-menu/#configuring-the-context-menu)

```
const gridOptions = {
  columnDefs: columnDefs,
  getContextMenuItems() {
    return [
      {
        name: 'CSV Export',
        action: function(params) {
          gridOptions.api.exportDataAsCsv({
            processCellCallback: function(cell) {
              // Manipulate the value however you need.
              return cell.value;
            },
          });
        },
      },
    ];
  },
};
```

The idea is to get the `CSV Export` and programmatically add what you need to happen in the `action`.  On the action, what you need is to call the `exportDataAsCsv` function from the `gridOptions.api`. Now (I know this is a ton of information) one of the options you have is to include your `processCellCallback` function where you can make sure you pass the cell value. Doing so is very useful because you can manipulate the value however you may need (e.g. Adding a $ sign to a number that is supposed to be money).

Custom button:

There is not much to say in the case you need a custom button. The only thing you would need to do is make sure you call the `exportDataAsCsv` on the gridOptions.api when onclick event is fired.

Something like:

```
onClick() {
  gridOptions.api.exportDataAsCsv({
    processCellCallback: ...
  });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As another answer mentions, the ag-grid docs specifically state "Cell Renderers will NOT be used":
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-excel/#what-gets-exported

I did a workaround that calls the cellRenderer from the processCellCallback function, like this:

```
processCellCallback: function (cell) {
    var cellVal = cell.value;
    if(_.get(cell, 'column.colDef.cellRenderer')) {
        cellVal = cell.column.colDef.cellRenderer({value: cell.value});
    }
    return cellVal;
}
```

Comment: I get an: error  '_' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: I figured out what you were doing and updated it with what can be done today.   Just do an "if ( cell.column.colDef.cellRenderer ) {" instead does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

A lil late to the party but I recently had the same inconvenience, missing the raw values because four columns needed the cellRenderer and as you know per the docs those values will not be used. In my example I needed to plug in the raw values for in_progress, complete, unanswered, & needs_review

```
gridApi.exportDataAsExcel({
  ...
  processCellCallback: (params) => processCells(params)
});


const processCells = (cell) =>  {
    let cellVal = cell.value;
    const { 
      in_progress, 
      complete, 
      unanswered, 
      needs_review 
    } = cell.node.data.percentageStatus; // raw data source

    if(!cell.value){ // for the 4 cols this was always undefined
      switch(cell.column.colId){
        case "in_progress":
          cellVal = in_progress;
          break;
        case "completed":
          cellVal = complete;
          break;
        case "unanswered":
          cellVal = unanswered;
          break;
        case "needs_review":
          cellVal = needs_review;
          break;
        default:
          cellVal = "n/a";
      }
    }
    return cellVal;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found these answers a little confusing. Hoping to help the next dev looking into this. Vue JS with Vux store.

```
const actions = {
exportPurchaseOrderLines({ state: stateObject }) {
    //set gridApi in state
    stateObject.gridApi.exportDataAsCsv({
        // nice file name
        fileName: `${stateObject.order.number}-export`,
        // select only selected rows
        onlySelectedAllPages: true,
        processCellCallback: (params) => {
            // use the header name to determine which column to process
            if (params.column.colDef.headerName === 'Linked bills') {
                // if there are linked bills, return the bill numbers
                if (params.node.data.bills.length > 0) {
                    return params.node.data.bills.map((bill) => bill.number).join(', ');
                }
            }
            // return all the other cells without issues
            return params.value;
        },
    });
},
// more actions .....
};
```

Answer (score -1):

This is how I solved this issue :

When I call the export function the params arg in the cellRenderer function is not the same when the grid is loaded, the params arg looks like this when we export :

```
{export:true, value: "{...}"}
```

the `value` is the value in the field key, so in the cellRenderer function I had to do like this :

```
if(angular.isDefined(params.export)){
    return JSON.parse(params.value.slice(1, -1)).name;
}
```

Notice that double quotes are always added which looks weird, so when we have a string value in the field, `params.value` will look like this : `""theStringValue""`, that's why I use `params.value.slice(1, -1)`.